In what Disney film did a gelatinous cube appear?
The 1d6chan site contends that the gelatinous cube (a Dungeons and Dragons ooze monster created by wizards to keep their lairs clean) appeared in a Disney film; but not which film.
Does anybody recall seeing a cube-shaped slime in a Disney work and if so, which one?

Not the answer, but the title reminded me of Flubber, which is indeed a Disney film: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flubber_(film)

According to the Disney Fandom wiki, it was in the 2020 Disney/Pixar movie Onward.


On their way to find the Phoenix Gem at Raven's Point, Ian, Barley, and their father enter a dark chamber of 1,000-year-old dead knights to which upon arriving, the three encounter an enormous gelatinous cube chasing them across the way. During the chase, the cube absorbs Wilden's coat, cap, and shades, which suddenly disintegrates, just as the elf brothers avoid it and use it as a bridge to continue their way to find the Phoenix Gem.


Found by DDGing "gelatinous cube Disney movie"

Onward includes several DND / TTRPG references, in fact. The in-universe game role-playing game "Quests of Yore" is a major plot device.

It's the Shoggoth Cube!

AHHH!!!! RUN AWAY! DON'T LET IT DIGEST YOU!
